# MotionLayout ignores padding

Tags: android, animation, padding, android-motionlayout

I'm trying to animate margin, padding and alpha of a textview on swipe.
At the start, there is no padding of the textview, alpha is 1.
At the end, I want alpha to be 0, padding to be 100dp, 16dp dp margin on the sides, alpha to be 0.5
Everything works, except the padding is not changing.
Does MotionLayout support padding?
I'm using androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4.

adding more text since SO says that my post looks like is mostly code...
adding more text since SO says that my post looks like is mostly code...
adding more text since SO says that my post looks like is mostly code...

The layout xml:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/test">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fakenavigationBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:text="hello world">
    </TextView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

The motion scene:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/fakenavigationBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:padding="100dp"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
        </Constraint>

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/fakenavigationBar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
        </Constraint>

    </ConstraintSet>

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:duration="2000"
        motion:motionInterpolator="linear">

        <OnSwipe
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/fakenavigationBar"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="top"
            motion:dragDirection="dragDown"/>
    </Transition>
</MotionScene>
```

[image][image]

Comment: maybe other people will more understand if you explain what you're trying to achieve or share the screenshot

Comment: I added more details to the question.

Comment: Is there anybody here? Like for real, anybody? What can I do to make people see this post and help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a limitation of MotionLayout

Padding is not a supported attribute ConstraintSet and as such  does not support it.
There are not even methods on View setPaddingTop so they cannot be treated as custom Attributes.

This is a gap in MotionLayout but there are issues with padding. Padding changes the views measured dimension which request layout as the dimension of the view changes.
This is expensive because the only way to resolve the animation is to resolve the starting and ending constraintset and rebuild the interpolation.

It is best if you redesign you layout to use margins as this is the control of the Layout.

Answer (score 4):

I'll admit this isn't a very helpful answer but I've had the same problem with padding. Margins seem to work okay for MotionLayout but it does not appear to support padding. What I did to make mine work somewhat how I wanted was to add the padding in my MotionLayout file to whatever view I wanted. It respected the padding within that file but not within the Motion Scene Constraint Sets so it made it impossible to animate paddings in my situation. It would just keep the static padding that was set in the MotionLayout file which was enough for me to get by.

It does seem from [this blog post](https://blog.mindorks.com/getting-started-with-motion-layout-android-tutorials) that you could potentially animate between paddings if you set your Motion Scene transition to be between two distinct layouts as opposed to ConstraintSets.

I have asked a question to a few different resources about why MotionLayout doesn't support padding and will update my answer if I get anything useful but as far as I can tell, animating padding values isn't supported in MotionLayout.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it apparently comes at a large performance cost.

Add a `MotionLayout.TransitionListener` to your `MotionLayout` that calculates the correct padding value for a given progress value (0f-1f), and sets it to your view in `onTransitionChange()`:

```kotlin
motionLayout.setTransitionListener(object : MotionLayout.TransitionListener {
    override fun onTransitionStarted(motionLayout: MotionLayout, startId: Int, endId: Int) { }

    override fun onTransitionChange(motionLayout: MotionLayout, startId: Int, endId: Int, progress: Float) {
        val paddingInPx = calculatePaddingPx(progress)
        myView.setPadding(paddingInPx, paddingInPx, paddingInPx, paddingInPx)
    }

    override fun onTransitionCompleted(motionLayout: MotionLayout, currentId: Int) { }

    override fun onTransitionTrigger(motionLayout: MotionLayout, triggerId: Int, positive: Boolean, progress: Float) { }
})
```

Within your `MotionScene`, add:

`<Transition motion:layoutDuringTransition="honorRequest"/>`

See also: https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/issues/7#issuecomment-721447209

*Edit 1: although I was able to change padding with this technique, I eventually decided against using it because the performance impact was very noticeable on older devices.*

*Edit 2: There is also a issue related to scrolling animations, if you do a fling, then the `TransitionListener` callbacks are not guaranteed to be called, so the transition will reach it's start/end state without having updated the padding.*